# Generating UML class diagram from XML file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, uml, papyrus

I have to create plugin in eclipse papyrus for reverse engineering from DDL script to UML schema relational database. I've used JSQLParser, created Java represation and XML file.

This is DDL script for example:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE
(
Column1 VARCHAR COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
Column2 TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Column1)
);
```

and I've got this xml file:

```
<uml:Model xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/UML" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20131001" xmi:id="6fb3c342-4f98-4205-ad9d-3d1bafc5dad4" xmi:version="20131001">
<packagedElement name="Database" xmi:id="82a41c0a-8e79-43aa-b5f8-afd0f3d80ae8" xml:type="uml:Package"/>
<packagedElement name="TABLE" xmi:id="a74a1162-46d1-46a8-bfbb-d502cad593fa" xml:type="uml:Class">
<ownedAttribute name="Column1" xmi:id="4a5f62aa-ce54-4d01-90be-3a0eb71eca15" xml:type="7157ba11-e7a8-41d9-8854-cb6a6a52729e"/>
<ownedAttribute name="Column2" xmi:id="15c70181-dbf9-482c-aa8c-819bb1199150" xml:type="70970c80-ac38-441b-800c-6736c3eae035"/>
<ownedOperation name="PK" xmi:id="1edc5db7-3338-460a-acee-d552333d3106">
<ownedAtribute name="Column1" xmi:id="5449ae61-f297-42c0-bc18-2cc5e505bd1b" xml:type="7157ba11-e7a8-41d9-8854-cb6a6a52729e"/>
</ownedOperation>
</packagedElement>
</uml:Model>
```

Is there any way to generate class diagram from this xml file in Papyrus?